# (Ember.js) How to Share Model Data Among Unrelated Resources/Routes?

Tags: ember.js

What is the best way (the Ember way) to share model data among resources/routes that don't share a parent resource/route?

Details:

I have 2 top level resources (resource1 and resource2) whose model hooks retrieve almost the same data via Ajax, so their model hook code look almost the same as well, i.e. not very DRY. The difference is what they each do with that data.

The Goal: Keep resource1 and resource2 top level resources (or at least have their URLs look like they're top level resources), have them share some model data without duplicating model hook code.

Resource/Route definitions:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    ...
    this.resource("resource1", function () {
        this.route("routeA");
        this.route("routeB");
    });
    this.resource("resource2", function () {
        this.route("routeA");
        this.route("routeB");
    });
    ...
}
```

Desired URL's:

```
example.com/#/resource1/routeA
example.com/#/resource1/routeB

example.com/#/resource2/routeA
example.com/#/resource2/routeB
```

*NOT* [nested within a common resource] like this:

```
example.com/#/resource0/resource1/...
example.com/#/resource0/resource2/...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write a mixin with the common model hook. Make the resource1 and resource2 route extend from it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, blessenm. I considered a mixin, but decided against it- a mixin doesn't really remove the duplication, it just hides it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    ...
    this.resource("resource0", { path: "/" }, function () {
        this.resource("resource1", function () {
            this.route("routeA");
            this.route("routeB");
        });
        this.resource("resource2", function () {
            this.route("routeA");
            this.route("routeB");
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Specifying resource0's path to be "/" essentially removes "resource0" from the URL path, making resource1 and resource 2 look like top level resources. Then I factored out any duplicate model hook code from resource1 and resource 2 into resource0's model hook.